# HAR model estimation in R studio

Tags: time-series, forecasting, estimation, volatility-forecasting

After splitting my data as the "in and out-of-sample" for volatility forecasting purpose in R, I estimate HAR model, but my estimated HAR model is for the whole sample. It does not estimate for the in sample. is there any specific code to include only in-sample?

Comment: i just found the code:                                                      
HARestimate(vRealizedMeasure = rv5_SPX[1:1917], vLags = c(1,5,22)) just need to specify time interval after your variable as above